# Is it safe to lower the S550 (2015+) Mustang by 1" in the northeast US?

Tags: ford, suspension, mustang

I have seen 5.1" and 5.9" listed as the ground clearance on the S550 (2015+). I don't know which is true, but I would like to lower the one I have ordered by 1" to improve handing.

Is this safe to do in the northeast US or will common road imperfections and ramps damage the underside of the vehicle?

If a specific set of springs is needed in order to answer this question, consider the Ford Racing Handing Pack.

Finally, what is the actual ground clearance of the S550 and the S197 (previous generation)? What about approach, departure, and crossover angle?

Answer (score 1):

1" is a decent drop and it will depend on what else you are changing. If you're just using springs to lower the vehicle, then you'll probably have issues with bumps and your struts going out faster or even banging loudly as they bottom out. If you're going to do that, then you should consider going with struts designed for lowered vehicles or find a set of coilovers that will give you the drop you are looking for. The Mustang aftermarket is massive and there is no shortage of options.

Another issue you may run into is rubbing. 1" may be fine, or it may rub on the fenders. Some people add negative camber to help the rubbing. Keep in mind that while 1" may sit right and look good, it might be that way when you drive over bumps, dips and pot holes.  Also keep in mind the differences between the front and rear.

Roush has a set of coilovers with a 1.5" front drop and 1.0" rear drop, so a 1" should be fine as long as you do more than just springs.

Stock ground clearance for a 2015 is 5.9" and 6" for 2013/2014.

Comment: I am planning on using the Ford Racing Handing Pack which lowers by 1" all around (quoted) and 1.25 front and 0.75 rear (observed).

Comment: Then I'd say you'll be fine as long as you don't have any extra body kit parts that hang lower than the stock body.